# AJAX Post twice in Laravel framework

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

i was searching in stackoverflow with the same title, but i got no luck.. this is my ajax script

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
        }
    });

    $('#btn-submit').on('click', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var nama_kelompok_jalan = $('input[name="nama"]').val();
        var action = $('#csrf-token').attr('action');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:action,
            data:{nama:nama_kelompok_jalan},
            success:function(data){
                alert(data.success);
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Tidak ada pelanggan yang dipilih');
            }
         });
    });
```

here my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $name    = $request->nama;
        $nometer = $request->nometer;

        $kelompok       = new Kelompok;
        $kelompok->nama = $name;
        $kelompok->save();
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Data Kelompok telah tersimpah..']);
    }
```

and this is my blade

```
              <input type="hidden" action="{{route('kelompok.store')}}" name="_token" id="csrf-token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" />
                <div class="kt-portlet__body">

                    {{-- <div class="form-group form-group-last">
                        <div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">
                            <div class="alert-icon"><i class="flaticon-warning kt-font-brand"></i></div>
                            <div class="alert-text">
                                The example form below demonstrates common HTML form elements that receive updated styles from Bootstrap with additional classes.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> --}}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nama Kelompok</label>
                        {{Form::text('nama', '', ['min'=>'1','max'=>'30','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'E.g: Juanda','required'])}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="kt-portlet__foot">
                    <div class="kt-form__actions">
                        <button id="btn-submit" type="btn" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
```

which is i dont use laravel form to avoid double post from laravel and ajax, but i still got double post, i try inspect element in network section my script load just one not twice, i try console.log response data from controller just one, but in mysql i got two new insert data with same value..
any sugestion for me??, thank you...

one more mistery.. in my development environment on my laptop is working properly, this is on server with production environment, both have php 7.3 with same configuration on php.ini

Comment: How many times you debug ?

Comment: maybe it's a multiple submission issue... try to disable the button after hitting it and see

Comment: do you have form tag ? if yes then share ?

Comment: @RishiRaut to many, i dont know what i lost here

Comment: @RishiRaut i dont use tag, thas all my script

Answer (score 1):

i solved my problem with remove this `location.reload();`

i dont know why... ahahaha, thank you everybody..

Answer (score 0):

The part `type="btn"` is invalid. You should try with `type="button"`. It's probable that because of the invalid button type, the button is interpreted as a submit button.

The code should be

```html
<button id="btn-submit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

You probably mixed it up with the Bootstrap classes.

Comment: it doesn't metter, i just avoid type="submit", it still post from ajax not from laravel

Comment: Please try changing it. I promise it would work, basically the value `btn` for attribute type doesn't exist. Check this, click on each button and see what happens. https://jsfiddle.net/2wu8sxod/

Comment: Also, even if you avoid the button type, the default button type is submit, so you specifically have to indicate `type="button"`.

Comment: nope.. not working, i just try it.. but thank you for suggestion...

Comment: i just try this <input id="btn-submit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</input>, post from ajax stil working but same problem, twice post

Comment: "i try inspect element in network section my script load just one not twice" indicates your problem is you've loaded your JavaScript on the page more than once. It's not going to be fixed by changing the JS itself, but by finding where the `<script src="foo.js"></script>` tag is double-dup.

Comment: Actually, that structure is wrong, it should be `<input id="btn-submit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />`. If you could provide an online version of your code we might be able to help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of changes you need to make

```
<button id="btn-submit" type="btn" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
```

And then in your javascript

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
    }
});

function submitForm() {

    var nama_kelompok_jalan = $('input[name="nama"]').val();
    var action = $('#csrf-token').attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: action,
        data: {
            nama: nama_kelompok_jalan
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.success);
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Tidak ada pelanggan yang dipilih');
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Still Post twice ?

Comment: yup.. i confusing cause it working properly on my laptop, but this is on server, both same php version and configuration..